# Unable to import GoogleCloudMessaging class

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

Im trying to implement **GCM Client** in my app.
I follow [this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) article.
All thing is fine till i try this part:

```
if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
```

My problem is i cant find **GoogleCloudMessaging** class to import it !
Its a screen shot from my import section: 
[image]
and i get this error when i try to rebuild my project:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable GoogleCloudMessaging
  location: class com.example.app.activity.HomeGroupActivity
```

I added google-play-services library into my project and use for g+ sharing and i dont have problem with it.

Comment: where is your `gradle.build` file? post it. Also check your `google_play_services version` it must `> 5.3`

Comment: So how you used `google_pay_service lib`? Are you on `Eclipse` or in `Android Studio`?

Comment: Im using intelij idea ! i import the module and library from sdk-folder/extras

Comment: That's wrong way. check this [http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#play-services](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#play-services)